# 453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Has anyone who has paid for Basic tier Twitter API resolved the "403 Forbidden" error in the title above? Here is my code and some output.

```py
import tweepy

consumer_key = "XXXXXXredactedXXXXXX"
consumer_secret = "XXXXXXredactedXXXXXX"
access_token = "XXXXXXredactedXXXXXX"
access_token_secret = "XXXXXXredactedXXXXXX"

client = tweepy.Client(
consumer_key=consumer_key, consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
access_token=access_token, access_token_secret=access_token_secret
)

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

query = 'irregardless'
max_tweets = 100

searched_tweets = [status for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=query).items(max_tweets)]
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Forbidden                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 20
17 query = 'irregardless'
18 max_tweets = 100
---> 20 searched_tweets = [status for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=query).items(max_tweets)]

...

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py:271, in API.request(self, method, endpoint, endpoint_parameters, params, headers, json_payload, parser, payload_list, payload_type, post_data, files, require_auth, return_cursors, upload_api, use_cache, **kwargs)
269     raise Unauthorized(resp)
270 if resp.status_code == 403:
--> 271     raise Forbidden(resp)
272 if resp.status_code == 404:
273     raise NotFound(resp)

Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here:
```

I tried reading Stack Overflow, using different Tweepy code, the Tweepy documentation, Twitter Developer documentation, tutorial videos, and developer forums. Nearly all information either predates the new paid Basic tier API plan or is people who haven't paid hoping their old code will work.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are trying to call the **Twitter API v1.1**, which can only be used for **Media Uploads**.

Remove the following piece of code as you have to use the **Twitter API v2**:

```py
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

And, you can no longer use the `tweepy.cursor()` and the `api.search_tweets()` functions.

Instead, you can use the `client.search_recent_tweets()` and the `tweepy.Paginator()` functions.

So, replace:

```py
searched_tweets = [status for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=query).items(max_tweets)]
```

with the following line of code:

```py
searched_tweets = tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets, query=query,
                                max_results=max_tweets).flatten(limit=max_tweets)
```

**OR**

If you are planning to retrieve a maximum of 100 tweets at a time, then you don't need **Pagination**.

So, you can use the following line of code:

```py
searched_tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, max_results=max_tweets)
```

For more information:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.search_recent_tweets

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/v2_pagination.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. Using Pagination got me unstuck.